# How was the first ribosome theorized to have been made?

Tags: cell-biology, abiogenesis, ribosome

Seeing as ribosomes are what help perform the act of translation itself, and the blueprints for they themselves are in nucleotide sequences, how was the first ribosome theorized to have been made? Also, before there were any ribosome, how was translation theorized to have taken place?

Comment: Don't have time to write a complete answer, but you may want to start by reading about the [RNA world hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_world_hypothesis), [ribozymes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribozymes) and [the central dogma of molecular biology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_dogma_of_molecular_biology)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An interesting take on this question is addressed in **Bokov and Steinberg's hypothesis**.

They have proposed the ribosome has evolved from a short length (~110bp) of RNA that did not have the translational activity that we associate with ribosomes today.

Instead this short length of RNA carried out alternative functions on RNA in RNA based life. Then overtime the accumulation of mutations occurred, such as duplication events that allowed the RNA strands to fold around one another forming a larger unit. This larger unit may have been able to add building blocks together. Over time natural selection will have guided these strands to be more precise in their building actions.

The details of course aren't entirely filled in yet (it's difficult to do because how long ribosomes have been a staple of life), but it's important to take any seemingly complex structure in organisms, and break them down into potentially useful intermediate evolutionary steps.

Some more reading on this subject here -

- [An article giving a background of Bokov and Steinberg](http://blogs.sciencemag.org/origins/2009/02/deconstructing-the-ribosome.html)
- [Bokov and Steinberg's 2009 paper (believe it's paywalled)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v457/n7232/full/nature07749.html)
- [Origin and Evolution of the Ribosome (paper)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2926754/)